# Pandas multiply between columns does not work

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following multiindex `jpy_bal` dataframe:

```
                        2019-07-28 00:00:00  2019-07-29 00:00:00     (2019-07-28 00:00:00,)  (2019-07-29 00:00:00,) 
app_vendor_id currency                                             
3             1WO                       262                  262              2.418967e+00            2.517868e+00 
              ABX                        10                   10              9.226124e-01            1.037273e+00   
...                                     ...                  ...                   ...                     ...  
29193         BCH                         8                    8              3.372592e+04            3.352354e+04

[129 rows x 4 columns]
```

I try then to multiply with the following code:

```
jpy_bal.iloc[:,[0]] = jpy_bal.iloc[:,[0]] * jpy_bal.iloc[:,[3]]
```

But this give me the following output:

```
                        2019-07-28 00:00:00  2019-07-29 00:00:00     (2019-07-28 00:00:00,)  (2019-07-29 00:00:00,) 
app_vendor_id currency                                             
3             1WO                       Nan                  262              2.418967e+00            2.517868e+00 
              ABX                       Nan                   10              9.226124e-01            1.037273e+00   
...                                     ...                  ...                   ...                     ...  
29193         BCH                       Nan                    8              3.372592e+04            3.352354e+04

[129 rows x 4 columns]
```

I have `Nan` instead of the result. Would you know why this could happen? Any contribution is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please show the dataframe more neatly?

Comment: What are the dates out there? is it a column or sth else?

Comment: you can use a sample dataframe to highlight what you think could be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not multiplying two series but you are multiplying two dataframes because you call `iloc[:, [0]]` instead of `.iloc[:, 0]`. This will use the column index AS WELL AS the row index and not find a match.

try
`jpy_bal.iloc[:, 0] * jpy_bal.iloc[:, 3]`

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

# 2 dataframes with same index, works as expected.
df.iloc[:, [0]] * df.iloc[:, [0]]

# 2 dataframes with different index, yields a 2x2 matrix with NaN's
df.iloc[:, [0]] * df.iloc[:, [1]]
```

*Result*

```
    0   1
0 NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN
```

**Corrected code**

```
df.iloc[:, 0] * df.iloc[:, 1]
```